# Rails application using Postgres adapter can't activate pg

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails application, with a bare `pg` requirement in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'pg'
```

You'll get the following error:

```
Gem::LoadError can't activate pg (~> 0.18), already activated pg-1.0.0. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.
```

Comment: The same thing happens for Sinatra applications as well

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The `pg` gem recently released version `1.0.0` which is not yet compatible with Rails.

If you're on Rails 5, change your Gemfile's `pg` requirement to the following<sup>1</sup>:

```
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
```

or on Rails < 5, this:

```
gem 'pg', '~> 0.11'
```

And then run

```
bundle update pg
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Bundler will effectively do the exact same thing with either line, but this way you'll match the Rails source code's [runtime check](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/71f4758c50fca5220429365c23b014458e7341f6/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb#L2) exactly, as well as the version emitted by `rails new`'s Gemfile generator.

Comment: Bundler attempted to update pg but its version stayed the same