# Gem::LoadError: can't activate pg (~> 0.18), already activated pg-1.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, bundler, rails-migrations

I've been doing the Rails tutorial found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and have been successful up to the point of having to migrate the Comments migration using **$ rails db:migrate**. Prior to this point, I've been able to generate the Article model and migrate the Articles create migration with no issues. In between these two migrations, nothing has changed in my Gemfile, so I'm not sure what it is Bundler is having an issue with.

Here are the errors, followed by the full command-line output, along with my Gemfile and schema.rb:

```
Gem::LoadError: can't activate pg (~> 0.18), already activated pg-1.0.0.

Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
```

**Full command-line output**

```
xxx:gangelo: ~/dev/rails/test/blog (master*) ☠  rbenv exec rails db:migrate
rails aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:188:in `rescue in spec'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:185:in `spec'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:880:in `establish_connection'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:58:in `establish_connection'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `instance_eval'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `with_execution_control'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:65:in `execute_hook'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_load_hooks'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:326:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:6:in `<class:MySQLDatabaseTasks>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:3:in `<module:Tasks>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:74:in `<module:DatabaseTasks>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:35:in `<module:Tasks>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:34:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:21:in `block in perform'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'

Caused by:
Gem::LoadError: can't activate pg (~> 0.18), already activated pg-1.0.0. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:186:in `spec'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:880:in `establish_connection'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:58:in `establish_connection'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `instance_eval'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `with_execution_control'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:65:in `execute_hook'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_load_hooks'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:326:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/base.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:6:in `<class:MySQLDatabaseTasks>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:3:in `<module:Tasks>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/mysql_database_tasks.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:74:in `<module:DatabaseTasks>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:35:in `<module:Tasks>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:34:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:21:in `block in perform'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/vendor/bundle/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/gangelo/dev/rails/test/blog/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.3.1'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# gem 'sqlite3'

# Use postgres as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

# gma - start
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5', '>= 3.5.2'
  gem 'rspec-activemodel-mocks', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.1'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails', '~> 4.8', '>= 4.8.2'
  gem 'ffaker', '~> 2.2'
  # gem 'timecop', '~> 0.8.1'
end
# gma - end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**Schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180110153949) do
  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "text"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
end
```

**Migration file**

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :commenter
      t.text :body
      t.references :article, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: use `bundle exec`, not `rbenv exec`

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201361/rails-application-using-postgres-adapter-cant-activate-pg

Comment: @LHH - that did it. Thank you. I don't get it; why was I able to migrate my Articles migration? Post it, and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: @katafrakt - '$ rbenv exec rails db:migrate' is fine, that's making sure I'm running the rails gem specific to my environment set up through rbenv.

Comment: It's probably a dependency issue. while you running rbenv exec rails db:migrate'' it is picking another version of pg gem.

Comment: @LHH - no actually, the issue was simply not specifying the pg gem version that active record needed. gem 'pg' defaults to the latest 1.0.0 which is not compatible with the active record version that comes with rails 5.1.4. I can run $ rbenv exec rails db:migrate OR $rails db:migrate, and they both work now that I'm using gem '~> 0.18' in my gem file. Why it worked the first time, I have no idea; either way, the rails version was the same when running $ rails db:.. or $ rbenv exec rails db:.. :S

Comment: Yes. earlier it was picking pg gem 1.0.0 default when you ran $ rbenv exec. Now you have changed your pg gem version to 0.18, so it is picking same from your Gemfile.lock and working  fine both commands.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Turns out the postgres gem version 1.0.0 is **not** compatible with Rails 5.1.4. When I changed the postgres gem version to '~> 0.18', everything worked fine:

Changed from:

```
gem 'pg' # Defaults to latest version 1.0.0 (not compatible with Rails 5.1.4).
```

Changed to:

```
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
```

Answer (score 74):

looks like pg 1.0 is not compatible with rails 5.1.4 at the moment.

```
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
```

0.18 worked for me.

Comment: Sigh... We have rvm, bundle and gem but somehow we still get cryptic error messages like `You need to type 'pg', not 'pg'!`. :-/

Comment: did you try gem cleanup pg and gem uninstall pg?